# Perform something only after completing doInBackground in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my `AsyncTask` I do a quite a long operation inside `doInBackground()` which assigns a value to a variable after completion of `doInBackground()`.
I use the value of that variable to setup a part of the user interface in `postExecute()`.
The problem is that `doinbackground()` is quite a long operation and `postExecute()` finishes first. That way I fail to obtain the value.

Here's what the problem is

```
private class bigwork extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    String foo = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        // Long operation sets variable 'foo' a new value
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        // Make use of foo here
    }
```

The problem is the value of `foo` I get in `postExecute()` is still `null`.

Comment: onPostExecute will always be called only after doInBackground() unless task is aborted. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result) . Are you missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would pass the String directly to onPostExecute:

```
private class bigwork extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
// Long operation
set variable 'foo' a new value
    return foo;
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String foo) {
    if (foo != null) {
        // success
    } 
// Make use of foo here
}
```

Comment: What if I want to make use of more than 1 variables?

Comment: Wrap in a class or create a list or array, if it is the same type of objects

Comment: Agreed, if your output is more than one type of object, consider wrapping them in a single class. That way it works with AsyncTask out of the box and your code is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameter directly to onPostExecute. Quoting from the [Android Developer Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> protected void onPostExecute (Result result)
>   Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground(Params...). The specified result is the value returned by doInBackground(Params...).

In case you need to pass more than one parameter wrap them in a class like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String string1;
    public String string2;

    public MyClass(String a, String b){
        string1 = a;
        string2 = b;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Override onPostExecute() function to perform some task after doInBackground() function has finished.Like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    jsonStr=sh.makeServiceCall(arg0[0], ServiceHandler.GET);
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.i("jsin", jsonStr);
    if(pd.isShowing()){
        pd.dismiss();
        }
    try {
        js = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray results =null;
    try {
        results = js.getJSONArray("results");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< results.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject c = null;
        try {
            c = results.getJSONObject(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            placeName = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            ratings = c.getDouble(TAG_RATING);
            HashMap<String, String> rest = new HashMap<String, String>();
            rest.put(TAG_NAME, placeName);
            rest.put(TAG_RATING, ratings+"");
            placeList.add(rest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    ListAdapter adapter  = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), placeList, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME}, new int[]{R.id.list_text});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I am making http request in my doInBackground and after successful reply i am parsing json in onPostExecute() and displaying in a listview and obviously this code is in class extending AsyncTask class.

Comment: If you want to pass more than one variable you can declare them global and use them freely in onPostExecute()..a simple suggestion :)